# How to see the dashboard of a downloaded wordpress website?

Tags: pages, dashboard, wp-redirect

I'm a web-developer(Html5,.net) but have never used wordpress or php.

I have a few changes to make in the pages of my website.
Now, **I've got the folder containing wp-admin, wp-includes, wp-content.**

For now I'm trying to make the changes in the downloaded wordpress website so how do I access the dashboard of wordpress?

I've installed xammp and configured the database and I can see the website being accessed properly on the localhost/website but when I try to access localhost/website/wp-admin it takes me to the developer's url (TEK Expertz developed this website initially) so when I go to localhost/website/wp-admin takes me to their(TEK Expertz) wordpress dashboard asking me for a user name or login.

Summary: Any possible way to change the content of the pages of downloaded wordpress website. P.S All pages are .php. 
I just need to make the text changes. Any direction in this regard will be appreciated.

Comment: look this page for details about moving a WordPress website https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

Comment: check your .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

1) your username and password can be admin/admin, but you can remember it by going to: **the database -> select the database -> click on the wp_users table and then enter the administrator record and update the password** *( function uses md5)*

Once the key has been changed go to: `localhost/myweb/wp-admin/`
Enter the user and the new password.

2) If your pages are in **.php**, you must do a process to insert the content to the WordPress database, but if you are a novice I recommend that you upload each publication one by one to Wordpress.

3) Search on [Youtube: Wordpress for beginners](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=wordpress+for+beginners+tutorial) Wordpress courses from scratch *(for beginners)* there is enough material for you to learn about the Wordpress administration.

If you have any doubts, do not hesitate to consult.